# Is It possible to have canvas in the background and other elements on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have canvas in the background that fits whole page + other html elements on it. Is it possible?

If it's not possible can I somehow draw on the background without canvas?

Comment: Yes, just give the canvas: `position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100&; z-index:1;` and the content above: `position:relative; z-index:2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with this CSS code:

```
#canvas {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   z-index:1;
}

#other_content {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    /* other styling */
}
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielLisik/48Xmz/1/)**

Comment: `html, body { height:100%; width:100%; }` is not needed. Moreover, it will make scrollbars appear because `<body>` has some margin by default.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I'm creating ui for my game that's why I need possibility to draw on the background. :)

Comment: @Vistritium aha! I suspected something like that. Good luck! :)

Comment: Good luck ! If you need any guides, have a look at my game:

https://github.com/Kaizeras/ChalgaScript

Comment: I have run into some problems with this solution. Changing width and height in css doesn't change coordinates system. Actually this make sense but I need coordinates too. @HristoGeorgiev javascript solution did the trick. thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Just give your `<canvas>` element these rules and properties:

```
    canvas {
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%
    top:0; 
    left:0;

    }
   /* just-in-case styling: */

       html , body {
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;

    }

    * {

     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;

    }
```

Or, depending on what are you going to put on the canvas, you might want to add some javascript as well:

```
(function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
                context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

        function resizeCanvas() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

                /**
                 * Your drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will be reset when 
                 * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
                 */
                drawStuff(); 
        }
        resizeCanvas();

        function drawStuff() {
                // do your drawing stuff here
        }
})();
```

Here is a **[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/qFuDr/)**

This makes the canvas a little bit more heavier for the browser, but resizes dynamically with the screen. It also ensures your animations look properly.

Comment: Those aren't attributes. They are CSS rules, which set some CSS properties.

Comment: True. Will rename them